# Get JavaScript object from c# with ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, object

I am building web app with .net, and I have a lot of settings and other data that I need to pass from the database with c# to JavaScript and use it with JavaScript.
What that I am doing now is to store all the data in array in c# and then pass it to JavaScript as array.
The problem is that I need to remember for each setting the index in the array. So I want to pass from c# some JavaScript object like this:

Settings{
Height: "67",
Width:"2.5",
Etc..
}
And than get the setting with only knowing the name like: var height = settings.height

Is there a way to create this kind of object in c#, and to use its in js?

Comment: Have you looked at Json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U can use [System.Web.Helpers.Json](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Web.Helpers.Json%29;k%28SolutionItemsProject%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true).Encode() method to serialize your object to [json](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) string. And in your javascript you can use `$.parseJSON(jsonString)` to deserialize it and use like javascript object.

```
public class Settings {
    public double Width {get;set;}
    public double Height {get;set;}

    public string ToJson()
    {
        return Json.Encode(this);
    }
}
```